# In a c program, does the whole process terminates when the main thread terminate?

Tags: c, multithreading, unix, process, linux-kernel

In linux, the whole process exits when the main thread terminates no matter how it terminates,by the function exit() or returns from main. If the main thread returns from main(),it will return to the "C runtime" known as crt.o or something like that. In the crt.o,whose c code like this: exit(main(argc, argv)); exit() will be called by the main thread
eventually, as a result, all the threads terminate.

Does my thought seem right?

If in the crt.o exit() is replaced by a thread terminating function like void thread_exit(int),which can only terminates a thread with an exit status, the c source code of crt.o seems like thread_exit(main(argc,argv)),do other thread still run when the main thread terminates?

Comment: It feels like it'd be faster to write a test program to tell than to write a question :)

Comment: @sarnold: Writing a test program is rarely the correct way to answer a question like this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Returning from `main` is equivalent to calling `exit`, and terminates the *process*. To terminate just a single thread, use `pthread_exit`. Note that it's valid for the initial thread to call `pthread_exit` (and the process does not terminate until all threads have exited or until one of them calls `exit`) and threads other than the initial thread implicitly call `pthread_exit` if you return from their start functions.

Answer (score 5):

on unix, a process terminates after the last thread has been terminated. Note that this can be any thread, not just "main" thread. So, if you replace exit with `pthread_exit`, but spawned a thread before returning in main, your process will not terminate.

Comment: @MartinJames OP wants to know what would happen if we were to replace `exit()` by `pthread_exit()`

Comment: Yes, hmm.. strange thing to contemplate doing.